# Why is the test fails though being called with right parameters?

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have test, I simplified it to the point it looks like this ( code below ). Objectmapper works fine in tests in the same class.

```
       @Test
void shouldUpdateVote_whenPut() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when(voteService.update(5, VOTE_CREATION_ADRIANO)).thenReturn(VOTE_RESPONSE_ADRIANO);

    mockMvc.perform(
            put("/vote/admin/5")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(VOTE_CREATION_ADRIANO)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$", notNullValue()));
}
```

Test fails every time with
java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$"

I decided to check if the method is called with needed parameters.

```
 @Test
void shouldUpdateVote_whenPut() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when(voteService.update(5, VOTE_CREATION_ADRIANO)).thenReturn(VOTE_RESPONSE_ADRIANO);

    mockMvc.perform(
            put("/vote/admin/5")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(VOTE_CREATION_ADRIANO)));
    Mockito.verify(voteService, times(1)).update(eq(5), refEq(VOTE_CREATION_ADRIANO));
}
```

And it is successfull. The question is, why does the test fail? Is the problem with mockito.when?

Here is the controller method under test. Controller works fine, I've checked it many times.

```
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
public VoteResponseDTO updateAnyVote(@PathVariable int id, @RequestBody @Valid  VoteCreationDTO voteCreationDTO,
                               BindingResult bindingResult) {
    throwExceptionIfBindingResultHasErrors(bindingResult);
    return voteService.update(id, voteCreationDTO);
}
```

Comment: You have `VOTE_CREATION_MAMIA` and then you have `VOTE_CREATION_ADRIANO`

Comment: @Shadov I've updated the code, it was the mistake in stackoverflow topic but not in the code itself and the problem is still present

Comment: The matcher in mockito uses the equals method. You are serializing to json and spring is deserializing. If you haven't implemented your own proper equals method, the matcher doesn't match and uses the default action, which is return `null` in this case. So fix your matchers.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you, you were right, that was not easy for me)